# Javascript windows - Add a listener for speaker and microphone event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to bind an event listener to the windows object that checks if the browser is using the speaker and microphone.

My use-case is as follows: I have an application where the user can record audio and play it back. However, if the application has been idle for 60sec then I want it to reload.

I have added listeners to `mousemove` and `keypress` which prevent the application from reloading if they're getting called but I also want to prevent the reloading if the user is recording audio or playing it back.

The approach I can think of is adding similar event listeners for these cases (record+playback), but I cannot figure out how I can add listeners for them.

I need something like,

```
windows.addEventListener('speaker', () => console.log('user using speaker')

windows.addEventListener('microphone', () => console.log('user using microphone')
```

Does any such event exist? Or is there any way I can check if the browser is using the speaker+microphone?

Any lead will be appreciated!

Comment: This: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9078341

Comment: Could you give more context on what you're trying to make here? Do you mean to figure out if a speaker or microphone is available? Are you trying to record something and play it back over the speakers? And like @RandyCasburn says, research like hell, share you findings, etc.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier I have updated my question with more details. And I will update it more with my research finding as I go. Thanks!

Comment: None of these happen, because you _need to analyse a stream_. There are data events after setting up the microphone, you have to detect inactivity yourself. Here's a guide on listenening to the microphone with permission of the user.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API Then you need to hook an AnalyzerNode I think. Also, playback means you can just listen for media events on the audio element, no?

Comment: This looks like a good lead. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a `microphone` or `speaker` event.

But, you **can** create your own events with the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) constructor. I've made an example here which creates a `microphonestart` and `microphonestop` event. These events will be dispatched whenever a microphone stream starts or when the stream has been stopped.

```
async function getMicrophone() {
  // Use audio only.
  const constraints = { audio: true };

  // Create the events.
  const microphoneStartEvent = new Event('microphonestart');
  const microphoneStopEvent = new Event('microphonestop');

  // Create the stream.
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

  // You'll want to know if a stream has randomly stopped without the user's intent. 
  const tracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
  for (const track of tracks) {
    track.addEventListener('ended', () => {
      window.dispatchEvent(microphoneStopEvent);
    });
  }

  // Internal function to stop the stream and fire the microphonestop event.
  const stopStream = () => {
    const tracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
    for (const track of tracks) {
      track.stop();
    }

    window.dispatchEvent(microphoneStopEvent);
  }

  // Stream is running, fire microphonestart event.
  window.dispatchEvent(microphoneStartEvent);

  // Return both the stream and the stopStream function.
  return {
    stream,
    stopStream
  };
}
```

Now you can use this just like your example, the only difference is there are now two added events: `microphonestart` and `microphonestop`. You can listen for them on the `window` object.

```
// Listen to the microphonestart event.
window.addEventListener('microphonestart', () => {
  console.log('user using microphone');
});

// Listen to the microphonestop event.
window.addEventListener('microphonestop', () => {
  console.log('user stopped using microphone');
});

// Start the stream.
getMicrophone().then(({ stream, stopStream }) => {
  // Use the stream.
  console.log(stream);

  // Stop the stream when you need.
  stopStream();
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

As for you speaker; it's the same principle. However it does depend on what technology you're using. Do you use an `HTMLAudioElement` or the Web Audio API?

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you.